# Passing a string to strdup from global pointer to a 2D VLA array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am declaring the global variable `sym` this way:

```
extern char *sym; // in header.h
char *sym = NULL; // in main.c

//Then allocate memory within main()
char (*sym)[DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16] = malloc(sizeof(char[N][DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16]));
memset(sym, 0, sizeof sym);
```

However when try to pass a string `sym[i][j]` to `strdup` get `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`. It seems that I am passing a value instead of `const char *` but do not understand why:

```
char buf*;
buf = strdup(sym[1][0]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because `sym` defined in the main, is shadowing `sym` defined above main in file scope.

The argument passed to strdup is the first `sym` which is of type `char*`.

---

The size of sym, used here:

```
memset(sym, 0, sizeof sym);
```

is the size of the pointer, so the memset doesn't zero the entire object. 
Use the same method as in the allocation:

```
memset(sym, 0, sizeof(char[N][DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16]));
```

or even better store the value in an object so you won't repeat yourself:

```
const size_t sym_bytes = sizeof(char[N][DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16]);
```

---

Since the array sizes involved in the calculation are all constants, simply defined the global variable as:

```
extern char sym[N][DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16]; // in header.h
char sym[N][DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16];
```

and no allocation is needed.

Or you could allocate, in which case, only the outer size of the object can be changed:

```
extern char ( *sym )[DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16]; // in header.h
char ( *sym )[DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16] = NULL;  

int main( void )
{
    sym = malloc( sizeof( *sym ) * N );
}
```

and `N` doesn't have to be constant.

Comment: @thank you for your quick reply. But then how should I share this global variable between .c files?

Comment: @AP13 Don't define a new variable that shadows the global one.

Comment: the last 2 dimensions are constant but `N` it is not, it is only known at run-time, that's my problem.

Comment: @AP13 I have wrote an answer for exactly that problem, see the update.

Comment: No need for parenthesis her: `sizeof( *sym ) * N`, just  do `sizeof *sym * N` or for better readability: `N * sizeof *sym`

Comment: @alk Actually using parenthesis more readable. Your version looks like someone is multiplying three variables. It is also more consistent, due to sizeof requiring parenthesis when using it with type names.

Comment: It's not the `sizeof`-operator needing the parenthisis but the type to make it a valid argument,  that is a compound. `sizeof` cannot be applied to a type.

Comment: @alk Types by themselves do not need parenthesis. Operator sizeof requires that the expression is a parenthesized type. *6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators 2. The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
expression or the parenthesized name of a type.* But all that is irrelevant in the argument. In some cases you need parenthesis, and if consistency is valued, one should always use parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

The code presented is really, really confused.

First of all, these are fine and consistent in themselves:

```
extern char *sym; // in header.h
char *sym = NULL; // in main.c
```

This, too, is fine in and of itself (in C):

```
char (*sym)[DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16] = malloc(sizeof(char[N][DIM_2_SYM][BUF_16]));
```

Note, however, that it declares a *local* `sym`, different from the file-scoped one, with a different type.

This is legal, but it does not do what you want:

```
memset(sym, 0, sizeof sym);
```

`sym` is a pointer; its size is the size of a pointer, probably 4 or 8 bytes.  Supposing that you want to zero-fill the whole dynamically-allocated space, the easiest thing to do is probably to use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to perform the allocation.  It does the zero fill for you.

Given the error message, the `sym` that is in scope for these statements:

```
char buf*;
buf = strdup(sym[1][0]);
```

is the file-scope one, whose type is `char *`.  For *that* `sym`, `sym[1]` designates a `char`, and the second indexing operator is inapplicable to that.  On the other hand, that code would be acceptable for the local `sym` whose allocation you present.

You haven't presented enough information for me to suggest a fix, but do be aware that VLAs cannot have file scope.  You may therefore need to approach your problem differently.

Comment: @Many thanks, I see my errors. The problem is that I only know the dimensions of `sym` at run-time but the variable has to be global. What information would you need?

Comment: @AP13, as I said, you cannot have a file-scope / global VLA.  You probably should not rely on a global variable at all, but if do so then you'll need to (1) use an array with static dimensions, or (2) use a `void *` and cast to the correct (variably-modified) pointer type where you use it, or else (3) use a `char **` and perform the indexing computations via manual pointer arithmetic.  The latter two alternatives require the actual array dimensions to be known wherever the array is used.